# Using reverse function and removing whitespace for a set amount of information from a txt file

Tags: c++, io

I need to find a way of reading in the last 6 lines of data from a file.

For example if I have
1 
2
3 
4 
5
6
7
8
9
10

I need to read be able to get 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5.

This method outputs the last 6 numbers from the file however they are backwards and I need a way to reverse them and get rid of the whitespace it prints out.

I'm unsure on how to use reverse and which arguments are required from this - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char x;
    ifstream f("test.txt", ios::ate);
    streampos size = f.tellg();
    for (int var = 1; var <= size; var++){
        f.seekg(-var, ios::end);
        f.get(x);
        reverse(x);
        cout << x; 
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Alot of the information I can find on this kind of thing are reading in all the information in a vector from the bottom and reversing it which is not what I need.

Can anyone please advise?

Regards

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're already trying to read the file backwards, what do you need `reverse` for? Reversing what has been read backwards would yield the same result as just reading the file from the beginning. And, anyway, calling `reverse` on a single `char` doesn't make any sense - how do you imagine reversing one character? `reverse` works on collections (iterators) - as stated in the documentation link you've provided.

Comment: Apologies I need to read in the last 6 numbers from the file. But when I read them in they would be the opposite way round. For example 40 would read in as 04. So I need a way to show the numbers as they do in the text file. 
I got advised to read the file backwards.

Comment: Your confusion seems to come from the fact, that you seem to assume that `get` reads the whole "40". It does not - "40" is two separate characters: `'4'` and `'0'`. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to read all the numbers into the container and then use `reverse` to have them backwards. I would leave reading the file backwards as a future challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using vectors with the reverse function from algorithm to reverse the data read in from the file. This was then used to read in the last 6 pieces of data using a simple for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To get it in the "required order" , you can do

```
for (int var = size; var > 0; var--){
    f.seekg(-var, ios::end);
    f.get(x);
    if(x!=' ') // check if x is not a whitespace
    cout << x; 
}
```

EDIT: `x` is of type char , it can only contain a single character , either a white space or the number , so we can check if it is a whitespace character or not.

Also instead of

```
streampos size = f.tellg();
```

`size` should be set to the number of characters you want to extract from file. If you leave it like this, it will display all the content of file as initially `f.tellg()` will return `ios::beg` , rest , the loop follows.

`std::reverse` is exactly to reverse the contents or a container. What you did in you code will give compilation error.

```
reverse(x); // wrong x is of type char

string s;
for(input)
s.push_back(x); 
std::reverse(s.begin(),s.end()); // correct , will reverse the order of elements
```

Read : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/ , there is an example too.

Comment: Ah okay I think I understand now so all you did was swap the increment around. 
I now understand how the reverse function works which was well explained. Thank you. 
Do you have any idea how to remove the whitespace that is cout'ed to my programwhen I do it this way?

Comment: Using this code it shows the top 6 numbers in the text file rather than the bottom 6. I'm not sure why it now functions in this way.

Comment: @PapaSmurf send a copy of the `.txt` file ?

Comment: All the data in the text file is as follows:
60

50
45
43
43
23
10
6
With each number on a new line. What is the best way for to send it too you?

Comment: @PapaSmurf , it is due to the line `streampos size = f.tellg()` , you need to set the size to the number of charecters you want to extract from file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68139/discussion-between-abhishek-gupta-and-papasmurf).